# Connecting to Docker-Machine via docker-py on OSX

Tags: macos, ssl, docker, docker-machine, dockerpy

### Context

I am trying to use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) to connect to [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) on OSX.

I can't simply use the standard `Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')` since docker is running on a `docker-machine` Virtual Machine, not my local OS.

Instead, I am trying to connect **securely** to the VM using `docker.tls`:

```
from docker import Client
import docker.tls as tls
from os import path

CERTS = path.join(path.expanduser('~'), '.docker', 'machine', 'certs')

tls_config = tls.TLSConfig(
    client_cert=(path.join(CERTS, 'cert.pem'), path.join(CERTS,'key.pem')),
    ca_cert=path.join(CERTS, 'ca.pem'),
    verify=True
#verify=False
)
client = docker.Client(base_url='https://192.168.99.100:2376', tls=tls_config)
```

### Problem

When I try to run this code (running something like `print client.containers()` on the next line), I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname '192.168.99.100' doesn't match 'localhost'
```

I've been trying to follow the [github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/406) on a similar problem with `boot2docker`, ie. the old version of `docker-machine`, but I don't know much about how SSL certificates are implemented. I tried adding `192.168.99.100 localhost` to the end of my `/etc/hosts` file as suggested in the github issue, but that did not fix the issue (even after `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2376`).

Maybe connecting via the certificates is not the way to go for `docker-machine`, so any answers with alternative methods of connecting to a particular `docker-machine` via `docker-py` are acceptable too.

**UPDATE**
Seems like v0.5.2 of `docker-machine` tries to solve this via the `--tls-san` flag for the `create` command. Need to verify but installation via `brew` is still giving v0.5.1, so I'll have to install manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `docker-machine` v0.5.2 as detailed in the [release on github](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/). Then I just had to create a new machine as follows:

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox --tls-san <hostname> <machine-name>
```

Then I added `<hostname> <machine-ip>` to `/etc/hosts`. The code worked after that

```
from docker import Client
import docker.tls as tls
from os import path

CERTS = path.join(path.expanduser('~'), '.docker', 'machine', 'machines', <machine-name>)

tls_config = tls.TLSConfig(
    client_cert=(path.join(CERTS, 'cert.pem'), path.join(CERTS,'key.pem')),
    ca_cert=path.join(CERTS, 'ca.pem'),
    verify=True
)
client = docker.Client(base_url='https://<machine-ip>:2376', tls=tls_config)
```

where I replaced `<machine-name>` in the `CERTS` path and replaced `<machine-ip>` in the `base_url`.

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but I keep running into the following issue:

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.21/containers/create

In /etc/hosts I've tried both:

dockerhost 192.168.99.100

and:

192.168.99.100 dockerhost

Comment: @BercoBeute run `docker-machine ip` and use that IP.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like with the Docker-py v1.8.0 you can connect to Docker-machine like below;

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env(assert_hostname=False)
print client.version()
```

See the doc [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docs/machine.md)

Comment: thanks @cdagli but I wanted to remove dependency on environment variables and have all the configuration done by python code